# Прозрачный статус бар но цветной навбар

Tags: android, kotlin

Собственно вопрос в заголовке.

```
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
```

Не работает, статусбар остаётся того-же цвета что и window_background.

```
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
```

Работает, но проблема в том, что вместе с статус-баром к чертям собачьим сьезжает навбар (для которого мне нужен фикс цвет.

Transfluent не подходит ибо для него полностью прозрачный цвет указать невозможно.

Вообще вопрос интересен даже в целом как управлять статусбаром, ибо видел например отличное с точки зрения ux с полосой загрузки в статус-баре решение, но абсолютно не понятно как его рисовать.

Comment: Насчет последнего абзаца. Думаю, Вам будет интересно [это видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oD3020rJMX4)